# Problems with passing in a plain text file to flask.request

Tags: python, flask, text-files

I'm trying to pass in a plain text file as a Flask request. I noticed that, if I do

```
f = flask.request.data
```

I get a bytes array/ a weirdly formatted string. I tried

```
f = flask.request.data.decode("utf-8")
```

and got the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while trying to write f to a new text file.

I want to imitate the method 'readlines()' with the input text file but can't figure out how.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the string as if it were a json, and use flask.request.json to get it back.

Here is a sample code:

Backend

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

string = '123'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    return jsonify(string)

@app.route('/', methods=['PUT'])
def test_put():
    global string
    string = request.get_json()
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here the requests to interact with the server

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
r.json()
Out[1]: '123'

requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json='456')
Out[2]: <Response [200]>

r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
r.json()
Out[3]: '456'
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused how I would be converting my text file request to a string in the first place. I feel like even the string format of the file I'm getting has weird characters, and that's why I'm receiving errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of request.data:

```
request.get_data()
```